# Exact solution to a non-linear differential equation needed, if possible

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> I'd like to know how to solve the ODE
>
> $$\ddot{x} = \frac{x}{1 + ax^2}.$$

This equation represents the basic mechanism involved during the mass acceleration of an object by a Flywheel. Because the mass accelerates on the radial track, that crosses the Flywheel, the transfer of momentum from the Flywheel to the accelerating mass, produces a decrease in the angular velocity of the Flywheel. The solution to this equation would allow the tracking of the angular velocity change of the Flywheel over time. To simplify the presentation, the radial reference $r$ has been replaced by "$x$" and "$a$" represents a constant. The derivative of $x$ is in terms of time "$t$".

Comment: In order to get responses that suit your needs, please include **in the body of the question** your own thoughts, the effort made so far, and the specific difficulties that got you stuck.

Answer (score 2):

Your differential equation is autonomous. Therefore, the substitution $\dot{x} = f(x)$ leads you to

$$f(x) f'(x) = \frac{x}{1 + ax^2},$$

which is a separable differential equation for $f(x)$ with (implicit) solution

$$f^2(x) = \frac{\ln(1 + ax^2)}{a} + c,$$

where $c$ is an integration constant. In order to get $x = x(t)$, you now have to solve

$$\int \frac{\mathrm d x}{f_i(x)} = \int \mathrm d t$$

for getting an at least implicit solution for $x$. I doubt that there exists a closed form for this.